# OpenStack set global security rules which assigning as "default" to tenant

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I need to assign some rules to default security groups each time a tenant creating.
I know how to assign rules to a default security group of a specific tenant. But i mean changing the global one which copies on tenant creation time.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not aware of an option doing that except changing the code.

Comment: I'm creating another sec-group for each tenant after creation and create servers using that.